# while loop mysql_ error

Tags: mysql, loops

I am new in mysql loops. I'm trying to create a first simple loop but it gives me an error message (we have mysqlyog, and it doesn't show useful notes so I don't know what I've done wrong). This is my code:

```
SET @t1='2014-05-01';
SET @w=0;
WHILE @w<2 DO

SELECT COUNT(user_id), LEFT(@t1,7) AS mes_start_post 
FROM `user_activation` 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(1st_net)>=@t1 
;
SET @w = @w + 1;
END WHILE;
```

The message is:

```
5 queries executed, 3 success, 2 errors, 0 warnings

--------------------------------------------------

Query: while @w<2 do SELECT count(user_id), LEFT(@t1,7) AS mes_start_post FROM `user_activation` WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(1st_net)>=@t1

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'while @w<2 do
SELECT count(user_id), LEFT(@t1,7) AS mes_start_post 
FROM `user_a' at line 1

--------------------------------------------------
 Query: END while

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END while' at line 1
```

Of course I don't know what the error is.

Thanks!

**update:**
I posted sth easy but what I really need is sth like that:

```
SET @t1='2014-05-01';
SET @d1=30;

WHILE @d1<DATEDIFF(@t1, NOW()) DO

SELECT user_id, LEFT(@t1,7) AS mes_start_post
FROM `user_activation` 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(1st_net)>=@t1 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1st_net)<=DATE_ADD(@t1, INTERVAL @d1 DAY)

SET @d1 = @d1 + 30;
SET @t1 = dateadd(@t1, INTERVAL  30 DAY);

END WHILE;
```

Comment: Control flow statements like `IF` and `WHILE` can only be used in stored procedures, not queries.

Comment: Thanks, just to be sure: is there a way to do loops not using stores procedures?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't. All you can do outside procedures is SQL queries.

Comment: I don't understand the point of your loop, since you don't use `@w` in the query. You're just doing the same query repeatedly.

Comment: Code is hard to read in comments. Please update the question with what you really want.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a loop, you can join with a subquery that returns as many rows as the iteration count:

```
SELECT count, mes_start_post
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS count, LEFT(@t1,7) AS mes_start_post 
    FROM `user_activation` 
    WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(1st_net)>=@t1) AS subq1
JOIN (SELECT 0
      UNION
      SELECT 1) AS subq2
```